# Track mouse position in p5.js

Tags: p5.js

As a part of my project I have to print a certain phrase depending on whether an ellipse I drew is moving towards or away from the mouse:

"4- Update beast.message to say whether it is chasing or fleeing the mouse
Create and use a boolean variable called movingTowardsMouse
If movingTowardsMouse is true, the message should say 'Chasing mouse'
If movingTowardsMouse is false, the message should say 'Fleeing mouse'"

I was wondering what the easiest way for me would be to track the position of the mouse in order to complete this task. I've tried a few things but to no avail. Google hasn't been able to give me answers either. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is the code I have so far without any of my attempted solutions for clarity purposes.

```js
var beast;
var color1;
var color2;
var color3;
var movingTowardsMouse = false;
var mousePosition;
var smallPoint;

function setup () {
  createCanvas(600, 200);

var cStrength1 = random(100, 255);
var cStrength2 = random(100, 255);
var tStrength = 150;
color1 = color(cStrength1, 50, cStrength2, tStrength);
color2 = color(cStrength2, cStrength1, 50, tStrength);
color3 = color(50, cStrength2, cStrength1, tStrength);

beast = {
  x: 0,
  y: height/2,
  size: 50,
speed: 4,
color: color(255),
message: "Chasing mouse",
}
smallPoint = {
  mousePosition: mouseX,
  y: mouseY,


}

}

function draw () {
  background(255);

var oneThird = width/3;
stroke(255, 255, 255, 50);
fill(color3);
rect(0, 0, width, height);
fill(color2);
rect(0,0, oneThird * 2,height);
fill(color1);
rect(0,0, oneThird,height);

if (beast.x >0 && beast.x < oneThird) {
  beast.color = color1;
} else if (beast.x > oneThird && beast.x < oneThird*2) {
  beast.color = color2;
} else if (beast.x >oneThird*2 && beast.x < width) {
  beast.color = color3;
}


fill(beast.color);
ellipse(beast.x, beast.y, beast.size, beast.size);


if (beast.x > width) {
  beast.speed= -beast.speed;
} else if(beast.x <= 0) {
  beast.speed= 4;
}
 point(smallPoint.mousePosition, smallPoint.Y);

beast.x = beast.x + beast.speed;




fill(255);
 text(beast.message, 10, 20);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that nothing in your assignment (at least the part you posted) says that you should actually detect whether the ellipse is moving toward or away from the mouse. The way I read it, you should just create a boolean variable and hard-code it with `true` or `false` for now. My guess would be that you'll add the more complicated logic later.

But to answer your question, you wouldn't need to track the mouse in order to determine whether the circle is moving toward the mouse. You'd just need the plain old `mouseX` and `mouseY` variables.

However, you would need to track the circle's movement and compare it to the cursor position. You could track the previous position of the circle and the current position of the circle. See which one is closer to the cursor, which will tell you whether the circle is moving toward or away from the cursor.

But again, my guess is that you aren't actually supposed to do this. My guess is that you're eventually going to write some code that moves the circle based on whether it's chasing the cursor or not. The variable determines the movement instead of the movement determining the variable.